# Is purchaseToken of Android IAB globally unique?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I know that we can't use `orderId` as globally unique transaction ID in testing because `orderId` can be null.

In https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

> Note: Test purchases don't have an `orderId` field. To track test purchases, you use the `purchaseToken` field instead.

It is not clear to me whether or not `purchaseToken` is globally unique.

In https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

> A token that uniquely identifies a purchase for a given item and user pair.

It can be duplicate when it is a purchase for another item or user?

How can I identify all testing purchases?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is globally unique.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/security

> purchaseToken is globally unique, so you can safely use this value as
> a primary key in your database.